# how to insert filename without the path in vim

Tags: vim, filenames

I knew that in the insert mode i can insert the filiename with the path using <kbd>CTRL-R</kbd>-<kbd>%</kbd>.

But i'd like to insert only the filename without the path part. Is there a similar command for that?

Comment: Hmmm, for me `Ctrl-R %` already gives the basename. Maybe it depends on some configuration parameter? Possible same on Unix SE: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57555/vim-insert-current-filename-into-the-contents

Comment: You can use `:r! echo %` [Full credits for this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/57557/164925)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use

```
<C-r>=expand("%:t")<CR>
```

See `:help filename-modifiers`.

Edit

`<C-r>` is used in insert mode to insert the content of a register. `"%` is the register that contains the name of the current file.

`"=` is the expression register, it contains the result of the expression that comes after `=`:

```
<C-r>=2+27+6<CR>        --> 35
<C-r>=expand("%:t")<CR> --> file.txt
```

Comment: is this a map command ? Does this affect other C-R commands eg. <C-R> w

Comment: No, that's what you must type in insert mode to insert the filename without the path: `Ctrl+r`, then `=`, then `expand("%:t")`, then `Enter`. Sorry, there's no shortcut for that. If you want a custom mapping, add `inoremap <expr> <F6> expand("%:t")` to your `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski see `:help 40.2` in the user manual.

Comment: you can also use `expand("%t:r")` to remove the extension additionally (for those who don't care to read the help :)

Answer (score 2):

While in insert mode, you can use

```
CTRL-R =expand('%:t')
```

Comment: is this a map command ? Does this affect other C-R commands eg. <C-R> w

Comment: @schurik - romainl already did a thorough job of answering your comment. If something is still unclear, feel free to ask.